# Latest in HasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, has-one-through

Laravel 8.42 introduced the [`latestOfMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) method to the query builder, but it seems to be for the `hasOne` and `morphOne` relations only.

Is there a workaround to leverage this for `hasOneThrough` relationships as well? e.g.

```php
// A.php
public function latestC() 
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(C::class, B::class)
        ->ofMany('created_at', 'MAX');
}
```

Comment: try to use [latest()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest).

Comment: That's just an `orderBy` on the `created_at` column.

Comment: yes latest() with first() -> will order but will bring the "latest" and first in collection.

Comment: No but I bet @staudenmeir has a package.